# Using java Process builder to play wav file

Tags: java, process, wav, javasound, processbuilder

I would like to send the following command below from a java program, but not overly bothered about reading the response. any idea how I can do this

the command below plays the wav file from the command prompt

```
aplay ~/javafx/examples/PrayerTime/src/Audio/athan1.wav
```

I am trying the code below but it is not playing anything! from my java program

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "aplay ~/javafx/examples/PrayerTime/src/Audio/athan1.wav");
try {
Process process = processBuilder.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: 1) *"not overly bothered about reading the response"*  That could be the source of the problem.  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  2) Using a `Process` is usually platform specific.  Use the [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) API for a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is absolutely right when he writes ignoring the output is the core of the problem.

When you start a process via `processBuilder.start()`, you are basically launching another process *that has a life of its own*. It's fire and forget. The only feedback you get via thrown exceptions is when the actual *lauching* didn't succeed. It says nothing about whether the launched process succeeded in what it was supposed to do.

Since you don't see an error message, the launching of the process went fine.

Now, using `aplay` and `~` suggests, that you are on some kind of Unix, probably Linux. There a process prints regular output to the standard out stream and error output to standard error stream. It also returns an exit code, that indicates whether things went smoothly or not. Both the exit code (you can get it from the `process` object by using `waitFor()`) and the error stream (also available from the `process` object) give you all the necessary info whether a process succeeded and if not, why not.

That all said, you might really want to use `Runtime.exec()` as it is much less complicated—at least until you know how to call your process without error.